# xml root element missing

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml that i am reading from a url which when i viewsource looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <root>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Testing</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Testing2</name>
        </item>
    </root>
</xml>
```

when i ran the code below it keep saying root element is missing? i do have a root element.

```
public void myfunction()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.site.com/file.xml");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string[] arr = XDocument.Load(dataStream).Root.Descendants("Name").Elements().Select(element => element.Value).ToArray(); //error says root element missing
    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It might need proper doctype in the xml tag

Comment: since i have no control of the xml file, is it something i can fix in my code?

Comment: I've not used `XDocument` but the `XmlDocument.Load` doesn't return the actual document... could that be something to do with it?

Comment: @freefaller ok i will check to make sure if thats the error. thanks

Comment: Other than the fact that your query doesn't actually return anything, that document loads fine. Try reading from disk in a test.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot you are also right, it loads no content:-) i guess i stopped at root eliminate missing, i will complete the rest. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Name` element in your xml file. Xml is case-sensitive. You should use lower-case `name`:

```
string[] arr = XDocument.Load(dataStream).Root
                        .Descendants("name")
                        .Select(name => (string)name)
                        .ToArray();
```

BTW your `name` elements do not have nested elements.

UPDATE: If you want to get values of `name` elements, then simply cast these elements to `string`. You can also use `Select(name => name.Value)` here. Just don't try to get nested elements of `name` - they don't have any.

Comment: Correct but this would not result in `root element is missing`

Comment: @QtX agree, but provided xml cannot result in `root element is missing` - root element is there

Comment: You don't actually want the trailing `Elements()` call either, as this selects child elements of the "name" elements, of which there are none in your document.

Comment: @Menew what exactly you are trying to get from this xml?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot thats why I wrote BTW at the end of answer :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i am trying to get the content. your answer helped me eliminate the error, however, i got no content.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky how about if i wanted to get all the values from <root>?

Comment: @Menew you can parse these xml into dictionary: `Root.Elements("item").ToDictionary(i => (int)i.Element("id"), i => (string)i.Element("name"))`